# Why a package that don't contains java classes (but other stuff) is not putted inside the final jar when I build the project?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, jar, package

I am pretty new in Ant (I came from Maven) and I have the following problem

I hava a project named **GUI.jar** and an Ant script that build the project into a jar file

Into my project I have the following package: **com.myCompany.mySoftware.resources** and this package don't contain Java class but contains some resource file souch as **.properties** and **.png** files. (Eclipse show me the icons related to this package having a white color)

The problem is that when the Ant script build my final **GUI.jar** file, this file don't contain inside it the folder **/com/MyCompany/MySoftware/resources/**, and when I go to execute my **GUI.jar** file from command line I receive the following error message:

```
java.io.IOException: No localization could be found in '/com/MyCompany/MySoftware/resources/Strings_it_IT.properties'
```

This is the code of my **build.xml** Ant script:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Peacock Engine" default="default">

    <tstamp />

    <condition property="unix">
        <os family="unix" />
    </condition>

    <condition property="mac">
        <os family="mac" />
    </condition>

    <!-- ============================================ -->
    <!-- Load build properties                        -->
    <!-- ============================================ -->

    <property name="project.buildfile" value="build.num" />

    <property file="${project.buildfile}" />

    <property file="info.properties" />

    <!-- ============================================ -->
    <!-- Specify the classpath                        -->
    <!-- ============================================ -->

    <path id="project.classpath">
        <fileset dir="../../SharedLib/">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>

        <fileset dir="../../CrystalIceAdapter/Atmos/AtmosAdapter/Release/">
            <include name="atmosadapter.jar" />
        </fileset>

        <fileset dir="../../CrystalIceTasks/Release/">
            <include name="dataspace.jar" />
        </fileset>

        <fileset dir="../../CrystalIceTasksLib/Release/">
            <include name="taskslib.jar" />
        </fileset>

        <fileset dir="../../CrystalIceXMLHandler/Release/">
            <include name="XMLHandler.jar" />
        </fileset>

        <fileset dir="../../ShellExtBridge/Release/">
            <include name="shellExtBridge.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <!-- ============================================ -->
    <!-- The default target                           -->
    <!-- ============================================ -->

    <target name="default" depends="jar" />

    <!-- Elimina le cartelle contenenti le classi compilate ed i jar -->
    <target name="clean">
        <echo message="Into CrystalGUI build.xml clean target" />
        <!-- <delete dir="../Release" /> -->
        <delete file="../Release/*.jar"/>
        <!-- Elimina directory del jar finale -->
        <delete dir="bin" />
        <!-- Elimina directory delle classi compilate -->
    </target>


    <!-- ============================================ -->
    <!-- Set the path if the operating system is      -->
    <!-- U                                            -->
    <!-- ============================================ -->
    <target name="initMacPath" if="mac" depends="clean">
            <echo message="initMacPath: SETTING MAC PATH" />
            <!--<property name="path">${basedir}/../../../Mac/CrystalIce/CrystalIce/CrystalIce/Build/Products/Debug/CrystalIce.app/Contents/Resources/java/</property>-->
            <property name="path">${basedir}/../../../CrossPlatform/CrystalIceGUI/Project/data/CrystalIce.app/Contents/Resources/java/</property>
        </target>

    <target name="initUnixPath" if="unix" depends="clean">
        <echo message="initUnixPath: SETTING UNIX PATH" />
        <property name="path">/usr/share/XCloud/appl/lib/</property>
    </target>


    <!-- ============================================ -->
    <!-- Compile the java sources to classes          -->
    <!-- ============================================ -->

    <target name="compile" description="Compile the Java sources to class files" depends="init">
        <echo message="Into CrystalGUI compile.xml jar target" />
        <mkdir dir="bin" />
        <javac srcdir="${basedir}/src" destdir="bin" classpathref="project.classpath" />
    </target>

    <!-- ============================================ -->
    <!-- Copy the JAR dependency and the driver in    -->
    <!-- the right location                           -->
    <!--                                              -->
    <!-- UNIX and MAC version                         -->
    <!-- ============================================ -->

    <target name="init" depends="initMacPath , initUnixPath">
        <echo message="Into CrystalGUI build.xml init target" />

        <ant antfile="build.xml" dir="${basedir}/../../CrystalIceXMLHandler/Project/" />
        <ant antfile="build.xml" dir="${basedir}/../../ShellExtBridge/Project/" />
        <ant antfile="build.xml" dir="${basedir}/../../CrystalIceAdapter/Atmos/AtmosAdapter/Project/AtmosAdapter/" />
        <ant antfile="build.xml" dir="${basedir}/../../CrystalIceTasksLib/Project/" />
        <ant antfile="build.xml" dir="${basedir}/../../CrystalIceTasks/Project/" />

        <!-- Copy SharedLib jar files: -->
        <!--<copy todir="${basedir}/../../../../../../../../usr/share/XCloud/appl/lib">-->
        <!--<copy todir="/usr/share/XCloud/appl/lib">-->
        <echo message="Copy to: ${path}" />

        <copy todir="${path}">
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/../../SharedLib" />
        </copy>

        <!-- Copy EMC Esu Rest API: -->
        <copy file="${basedir}/../../EsuAtmos/EsuApi 2.0.3.1/build/emcesu.jar" tofile="${path}emcesu.jar" />

        <echo message="emcesu.jar copyed" />
        <!--
        <copy file="${basedir}/../../EsuAtmos/EsuApi 2.0.3.1/build/emcesu.jar" tofile="/usr/share/XCloud/appl/lib/emcesu.jar" />
        -->


        <!-- Copy atmosadapter files: -->
        <copy file="${basedir}/../../CrystalIceAdapter/Atmos/AtmosAdapter/Release/atmosadapter.jar" tofile="${path}atmosadapter.jar" />
        <!--
        <copy file="${basedir}/../../CrystalIceAdapter/Atmos/AtmosAdapter/Release/atmosadapter.jar" tofile="/usr/share/XCloud/appl/lib/atmosadapter.jar" />
        -->

        <!-- Copy xmlhanlder files: -->
        <copy file="${basedir}/../../CrystalIceXMLHandler/Release/XMLHandler.jar" tofile="${path}XMLHandler.jar" />
        <!--
        <copy file="${basedir}/../../CrystalIceXMLHandler/Release/XMLHandler.jar" tofile="/usr/share/XCloud/appl/lib/XMLHandler.jar" />
        -->

        <!-- Copy taskslib files: -->
        <copy file="${basedir}/../../CrystalIceTasksLib/Release/taskslib.jar" tofile="${path}taskslib.jar" />
        <!--
        <copy file="${basedir}/../../CrystalIceTasksLib/Release/taskslib.jar" tofile="/usr/share/XCloud/appl/lib/taskslib.jar" />
        -->

        <!-- Copy dataspace files: -->
        <copy file="${basedir}/../../CrystalIceTasks/Release/dataspace.jar" tofile="${path}dataspace.jar" />
        <!--
        <copy file="${basedir}/../../CrystalIceTasks/Release/dataspace.jar" tofile="/usr/share/XCloud/appl/lib/dataspace.jar" />
        -->

        <!-- Copy shellextbridge files: -->
        <copy file="${basedir}/../../ShellExtBridge/Release/shellExtBridge.jar" tofile="${path}shellExtBridge.jar" />
        <!--
        <copy file="${basedir}/../../ShellExtBridge/Release/shellExtBridge.jar" tofile="/usr/share/XCloud/appl/lib/shellExtBridge.jar" />
        -->
    </target>




    <!-- Rutigliano path MAC
    /Users/xdrive/Documents/XDrive SVN/Implementazione/Mac/CrystalIce/CrystalIce/CrystalIce/Build/Products/Debug/CrystalIce.app/Contents/Resources/java/httpclient-cache-4.3.jar
    -->

    <!-- ============================================ -->
    <!-- Pack the java classes in a jar file          -->
    <!-- ============================================ -->
    <target name="jar" depends="compile">
        <echo message="Into CrystalGUI build.xml jar target" />

        <!-- Define the property jar.classpath 
             You may need to reference classes in other JAR files from within a JAR file.

             For example, in a typical situation an application is bundled in a JAR file whose manifest 
             references a different JAR file (or several different JAR files) that serves as utilities 
             for the purposes of that application.
        -->
        <pathconvert property="jar.classpath" pathsep=" ">
            <!-- classpath container: it contains a set of path element pointing to some jars or directories -->
            <path refid="project.classpath" />

            <chainedmapper>
                <!-- A chainedmapper is applied to the project.classpath -->
                <!-- STEP 1: Remove all directory information from the path element. Ex: dir1/dir2/lib1.jar is trasformed in lib1.jar -->
                <flattenmapper />
                <!-- STEP 2: Will prefix every path element resulting from step1 with lib/. EX: lib1.jar will became lib/lib1.jar -->
                <globmapper from="*" to="lib/*" />
            </chainedmapper>
        </pathconvert>

        <jar destfile="${basedir}/../Release/GUI.jar" index="false">
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/bin" excludes="${project.pluginptrn}/** **/tests/**" />
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Specification-Title" value="Java Utility Classes" />
                <attribute name="Specification-Version" value="1.0.1-15" />
                <attribute name="Specification-Vendor" value="TechUb" />
                <attribute name="Created-By" value="${info.software.author}" />
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${jar.classpath}" />
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="ConnectDataSpace" />
            </manifest>
        </jar>
        <!--
        <copy todir="${basedir}/../Release/lib">
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/lib">
                <include name="*" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>

        <copy todir="${basedir}/../Release">
            <fileset dir="${basedir}" includes="data/*/**" />
        </copy>

        <copy file="${basedir}/../Release/GUI.jar" tofile="/usr/share/XCloud/appl/GUI.jar" />
-->

        <copy file="${basedir}/../Release/GUI.jar" tofile="${path}GUI.jar" />
    </target>


</project>
```

What can I do to solve this problem and have the content of my package **com.myCompany.mySoftware.resources** is put inside the folder **/com/MyCompany/MySoftware/resources/** of my final GUI.jar file?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: In your build.xml I can see no task that copies the resources to the location from where the JAR is packaged. It is up to you to fill this location with all the files that should be added to the JAR

Comment: You are right !!! But now the problem is: What can I do to copy the content of my com.myCompany.mySoftware.resources into the directory  /com/MyCompany/MySoftware/resources/ inside my GUI.jar file? I tryed to add this line in my jar task: <fileset dir="${basedir}/src/com/techub/crystalice/resources" /> to add also the these file...the problem now is that don't add it into the right directory in my GUI.jar file but put them in the root of the GUI.jar file

Comment: in your "jar" task you have defined that the content from ${basedir}/bin should be packaged into the jar. So you have to copy the resources into the correct location inside ${basedir}/bin before the jar task is called.